# Xamarin IOS Load View form Gesture Event

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to capture the PanGesture event, so when the user swipe with his/her finger anywhere in the view to the right, for example, the RightView shows up and when to left, the LeftView shows up.

I am using the code below. It is from Xamarin docs. I modified it a bit. My 'currView' is my outlet for the current View. When I swipe at the simulator with my mouse, the event gets captured correctly, but when stepping through (after break pointing) at the curly bracket of

```
    if (recognizer.State != (UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled | UIGestureRecognizerState.Failed
    {
```

The code loops between it and this one.

```
     HandleDrag(gesture))
```

once for every pixel (I think).

I am trying to trigger the load of another view, but didn't find a spot to place it at. I tried at the

```
    Console.WriteLine ("Here")
```

and at:

```
    currView.AddGestureRecognizer (gesture);
```

but every time the code finishes the loop, it just ignores it and execution ends. How can I make the loading of next view work?

The line of the comment:

```
    // NEED TO LOAD ANOTHER VIEW HERE
```

shows my desires spot to load another View.

Here is my code

```
namespace Example_Touch.Screens.iPhone.GestureRecognizers
{
using System;
using System.Drawing;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

public partial class GestureRecognizers_iPhone : UIViewController
{
    private RectangleF originalImageFrame = RectangleF.Empty;
    // The IntPtr and initWithCoder constructors are required for items that need 
    // to be able to be created from a xib rather than from managed code

    public GestureRecognizers_iPhone(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    [Export("initWithCoder:")]
    public GestureRecognizers_iPhone(NSCoder coder)
        : base(coder)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public GestureRecognizers_iPhone()
        : base("GestureRecognizers_iPhone", null)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();


        WireUpDragGestureRecognizer();
    }

    protected void WireUpDragGestureRecognizer()
    {
        // create a new tap gesture
        UIPanGestureRecognizer gesture = new UIPanGestureRecognizer();

        // wire up the event handler (have to use a selector)
        gesture.AddTarget(() => HandleDrag(gesture));
        currView.AddGestureRecognizer (gesture);
    }

    protected void HandleDrag(UIPanGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        PointF offset2 = recognizer.TranslationInView(currView);
        // if it's just began, cache the location of the image


        if (recognizer.State != (UIGestureRecognizerState.Cancelled | UIGestureRecognizerState.Failed
            | UIGestureRecognizerState.Possible))
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Here");
                            // NEED TO LOAD ANOTHER VIEW HERE
        }

    }
    private void Initialize()
    {
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Apple documentation:

`A panning gesture is continuous. It begins (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the minimum number of fingers allowed (minimumNumberOfTouches) has moved enough to be considered a pan. It changes (UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) when a finger moves while at least the minimum number of fingers are pressed down. It ends (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when all fingers are lifted.`

Check for `UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended` state and if it occurs, you can load another view.
From your description it seems that you could use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` instead of `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. The `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is a discrete gesture, so you don't have to check for states, you just implement it this way:

Somewhere in your code implement the handler:

```
private void HandleSwipeRight()
{
    // load another view
    Console.WriteLine("Swipe right.");
}
```

And initialize the gesture recognzier in `ViewDidLoad()`:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeGestureRecognizerRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(HandleSwipeRight);
swipeGestureRecognizerRight.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
this.View.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizerRight);
```

You can add another swipe gesture recognizer for a different direction.